# SharePoint Migration Tool is creating Rich Text type in target instead of Enhanced Rich Text

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepointmigrationtool

I am using SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT) to migrate my SharePoint 2013 site to SharePoint Online.

I have columns of type "Multiple lines of Text - Enhanced Rich Text". SPMT does create this type of column but it is creating it as "Rich Text" instead of "Enhanced Rich Text".

**Due to this my inline images (Image HTML Tags) are lost during the migration.**

Is there a way to force SPMT to consider all properties of "Multiple Lines of Text" columns?

If no, is there a way to do only site schema sync (Create lists, columns, views and etc.) but do not migrate data?

If yes, I could manually convert the Multiple Lines of Text columns to "Enhanced Rich Text" and then resume the data migration to ensure no data loss.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Whether only image tags don’t work as expected after migrating the content?

What’s the link of image in the tag? Make sure you can access the picture URL in the SharePoint Online.

If the issue exists, how did you set the column to display image? Please share the format with us.

Besides, you can convert to "Enhanced Rich Text" without data lose.

Comment: 1. Only image tags are missing in target content.Hyperlinks are migrated, of course, URL will be broken due as target server relative URL is different from source.
2. Img tag is not even copied to target as target is not "Enhanced Rich Text". Anyway, in my case img is pointing to item's attachment.
3. If there is a way such that SPMT creates "Enhanced Rich Text" directly or does schema sync so I will convert column type prior to data migration, then I will get "img" tag and then I can programmatically replace old server relative URL with new server relative URL which will solve my problem.